# Last <li> selector not working

Tags: jquery, html-lists

trying to select the last LI in this list and add a class to it - can't seem to make it work?? Any ideas what I have wrong here?

Baiscally want to add the class "noBottomBorder" to the last LI in the subnav list - e.g. in this example "Commercial" but can't hard code as subnav list is dynamic CMS controlled...

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul.subNavWrapper li:last-child").addClass("noBottomBorder");
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navWrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the Home page" class="navButton primaryLink01">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the Our Approach page" class="navButton primaryLink02">Our Approach</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The Process page" class="navButton primaryLink03">The Process</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the Examples of Work page" class="navButton primaryLink04">Examples of Work</a>

<ul class="subNavWrapper">
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The Extenstions page" class="subNavButton">Extenstions</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The Refurbishments page" class="subNavButton">Refurbishments</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The Kitchens page" class="subNavButton">Kitchens</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The Bathrooms page" class="subNavButton">Bathrooms</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The Bespoke Carpentry page" class="subNavButton">Bespoke Carpentry</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The General page" class="subNavButton">General</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the The Commercial page" class="subNavButton">Commercial</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the Press page" class="navButton primaryLink05">Press</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the Testimonials page" class="navButton primaryLink06">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the Fees page" class="navButton primaryLink07">Fees</a></li>
<li><a href="#.html" target="_self" title="Navigate to the Contact page" class="navButton primaryLink08">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have too many unclosed elements here. So it's hard to get what you want.

Comment: Baiscally want to add the class "noBottomBorder" to the last LI in the subnav list - e.g. in this example "Commercial" but can't hard code as subnav list is dynamic CMS controlled...

Comment: @dubbs then why not start from last subNav to make it easier?  `$('.subNavButton:last').closest('li').addClass('noBottomBorder')`

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS? Doesn't seem like JS is necessary.

Comment: CSS method would not work for IE browsers 7 and 8 :-) I want a bullet-proof solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated answer: http://jsfiddle.net/YQdL9/

just give the `.subNavWrapper` class `to ul`.

```
$(function(){ 
    $("ul.subNavWrapper li:last-child").addClass("noBottomBorder");
});
```

Comment: Thanks - but does not fix the issue... still does not add the class.. I can see the theory of how it should work... but something not right...

Comment: Are you sure you are doing this in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Thanks Jai - worked out the issue... I was adding the bottom-border to the <a> within the <li> so adding a nobottomborder class to the <li> was doing nothing... needed to be added to the <li> <a>! doh! thanks for your help... drove me mad for a few hours!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div.subNavWrapper li:last-child").addClass("noBottomBorder");
```

Comment: hmmm.. doesnt work - just updated the source in the question to remove the DIV inside the child UL... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **:last** selector

```
$(".subNavWrapper li:last").addClass("noBottomBorder");​
```

Also you have malformed HTML..

`</li>`  supposed to be `<ul>` for the last list..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Ub3BY/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The short answer with what little information I have:

I have to assume that the `<script>` element is executed before the `<ul>...` menus are built out. Because of this, the selector won't select any elements as they don't yet exist in the DOM.

jQuery has a convenience DOM ready event referred to as `document.ready`, but the shorthand for it is:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    ...your code...
});
```

It's similar to `onload`, but a bit more performant.

Your code should then be:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("ul.subNavWrapper li:last-child").addClass("noBottomBorder");
});
```

Which should select the correct elements assuming they have the correct names, and that I haven't made any typos.

---

That all being said, it looks to me like you're simply trying to put a single border between each element, without having a border hanging at the bottom. Instead of adding bottom borders to each element, you'd probably be better off adding *top* borders and removing the border from the first element:

```
li {
    border-top: 1px solid <color>;
}
li:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
}
```